# flutter dependency error suggest me changes in this file

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, flutter-dependencies, flutter-packages

This is my pubspec.yaml file.

```
name: hydrabadi_rishte
description: A new Flutter project.

#version: 1.0.1+2
version: 1.0.2+3

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.18.6 <3.0.0"
  flutter: ">=2.12.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  dropdown_button2:
  timer_button: ^2.0.0
  dropdownfield: ^1.0.0
  custom_radio_grouped_button: any
  checkbox_grouped: ^1.8.0
  dropdown_plus:
  http:
  pin_entry_text_field: 0.1.4
  pinput: ^2.2.8
  timer_count_down:
  flutter_countdown_timer: ^4.1.0
  flutter_search_bar: ^2.1.0
  quds_popup_menu: 0.0.1+1
  like_button: ^2.0.4
  rflutter_alert: ^1.0.3
  # custom_check_box: ^0.0.4
  dropdown_search:
  fluttertoast: ^8.0.9
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.15
  sizer: ^2.0.15
  animated_splash_screen: ^1.2.0
  file_picker: ^3.0.0
  share: ^2.0.4
  image_cropper: ^3.0.0
  carousel_slider: ^4.1.1
  smooth_page_indicator: ^1.0.0+2
  image_picker: ^0.8.6
  email_validator: ^2.0.1
  flutter_animate: ^3.1.0
  flutter_svg: ^2.0.5
  razorpay_flutter: ^1.2.6
  mailer: ^5.0.0
  video_player: ^2.3.8
  chewie: ^1.0.2
  flutter_rating_bar: ^4.0.0

  
  get:
 
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  url_launcher: ^6.1.11

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

  assets:`enter code here`
    - assets/
```

Suggest changes in the code

here is a screenshot of an error it gives for all version:

[image: Get Dependencies]

[image: Error]

As I'm new to flutter I got this code in GitHub and downloaded from there.

Comment: You can easily fix this by reading the helpful error message. Your current SDK is in null-safety but the package you're trying to add doesn't support null-safety.

Comment: can you give the changes in code as I'm new to flutter

Comment: Remove the `pin_entry_text_field` package from the list.

Comment: Seems like you have a lot of outdated packages. It's either you remove them or you downgrade your Flutter SDK. Another option is to use version manager like `puro` or `fvm`.

Comment: after removing it is showing like this .https://ibb.co/pfrkHgR.here is the screenshot of it

Comment: My current version is 3.0.6 I should downgrade to which version for implementation of this project

Answer (score 0):

You're probably getting the error because you forgot the **^** before the version on this line *pin_entry_text_field: 0.1.4*.

About suggestions for replacement look [here.](https://fluttergems.dev/pin-password-field/)

You could get error here *quds_popup_menu: 0.0.1+1* too.